# send File and Data in Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to send file and data together to Controller 
when I send File it work correctly but When I try to send data and file nothing I get.

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

and as I remove this codes I can send data
what should I do?

html code

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
    <textarea class="form-control" cols="40" id="desc" name="textarea" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class="">
        <div class="radio">
            <label class="radio">
                <input name="answer" id="respawn" type="radio" value="1" /> 1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label class="radio">
                <input name="answer" type="radio" value="2" /> 2
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label class="radio">
                <input name="answer" type="radio" value="3" /> 3
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</div>
```

controller code

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,

    ]);
}
```

ajax code

```
$("#offer").click(function() {
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var desc = $("#desc").val();
    var respawn = $("#respawn").val();
    var pic = new FormData();
    pic.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
    var offer = {
        title: title,
        desc: desc,
        respawn: respawn,
        pic: pic
    };
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/create',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
        },
        data: offer,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            alert("Successful!")
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url:'/create',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
    },
    data:pic,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(response){
        alert("Successful!")
    }
});
```

you were using formData in place of pic.

Comment: sorry but  I was working on some other functions and vars and I forgot to remove them 
I'm trying to send offer not formdata

Comment: Okay simply append the objects of offer into pic itself and send them.. it'll work

Comment: can you give me exact code?I don't Understand how it works

Comment: var pic = new FormData();
pic.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
pic.append('title',title);
pic.append('desc',desc);
pic.append('respawn',respawn);

**And SEND using:**

$.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/create',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
        },
        data: pic,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            alert("Successful!")
        }
    });